# TableView getSelectedIndex returning abnormal value

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX window made in Scene Builder with 2 active buttons and a TableView that stores Commodity items. Commodity is an interface that's implemented by 2 so far identical classes Product and Service. Relevant code:

```
@FXML
private TableView<Commodity> commoditiesTable;

commoditiesTable.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
            int selectedIndex = commoditiesTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            commoditiesTable.getItems().stream().forEach((c) -> {
                System.out.println(c.getName());
            });
            System.out.println(selectedIndex);
});

@FXML
//Button
private void setTableViewProducts() {
    commoditiesTable.setItems(DataSupplier.getProducts());
    System.out.println("Products");
}

@FXML
//Button
private void setTableViewServices() {
    commoditiesTable.setItems(DataSupplier.getServices());
    System.out.println("Services");
}
```

DataSupplier returns an ObservableList with 2 elements in both methods consisting of Id and name fields.
Triggering "setOnMouseClicked" works as expected until TableView is updated via other class' button, at which point

```
commoditiesTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
```

starts returning -1.

Output from this snippet of code after clicking on product button and selecting first element, repeating, then clicking services and products again:

```
Products
product1
product2
0
Products
product1
product2
0
Services
service1
service2
-1
Products
product1
product2
-1
```

Behavior is identical if I select elements other than first or start with Services before switching to Products.

Comment: Note: You don’t need a stream() to print all elements. just `commoditiesTable.getItems().forEach(...)`

Comment: It's not entirely surprising, is it? Clearly, when you reset the list of items in the table, the selection is cleared (so `getSelectedIndex()` will be `-1`). There are two things that happen when you click on the table: your listener is invoked, and the selection changes (if you click on a filled cell). I don't believe there is any guarantee as to what order those will occur in. If the mouse listener is invoked before the selection is changed, then you see the "old" selected index, i.e. `-1`. Otherwise, you see the "new" selected index. The behavior is not guaranteed to do one or the other.

Comment: I see, I wasn't aware of this. I wrongly assumed that selection change occurred before invoking listener.

Comment: Well, I just ran some quick tests, and in those quick tests it does (i.e. I can't reproduce the behavior you describe). But as I said I don't think there's any guarantee of it, so I would not be surprised if this were implementation dependent. What is your real use case for the mouse handler on the table wanting to know what's selected?

Comment: Well I was trying to get selection index for printing prices in different window and maybe later populating a ChoiceBox based on selected item's ID, I store that info in different objects. I just ended up using mouse listener to narrow down this behavior.

Comment: If you want to carry out some action when the selection changes, just register a listener with the selection model's `selectedItemProperty()`, i.e. `commoditiesTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(...)`. That way it will be invoked and the correct selected item will be available (and it will work if the user changes selection using the keyboard).

Comment: I figured it out! I didn't even notice but index was updating properly for every selected value except for value that was selected in old list because it was highlighting "new" row and probably still pointing to as you said old selected index. I added `commoditiesTable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();` to both buttons and it works now. Thanks for your help James_D!

Comment: you might consider self-answering (and accepting) your solution - thus it  will be more visible (vs. buried in the comments) for future readers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faulty value was generated because `commoditiesTable.getSelectionModel()` was still pointing to old ObservableList even though correct element was visually highlighted in the table. After calling `getSelectionModel().clearSelection()` on the table, `getSelectedIndex()` returns correct values.